# How to draw lines at given angle to the edge of contour?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Sample image:

[image: sample image]

How to measure the diameter or area of cell (particularly for white, grey and black) ?

I found some relevant idea which is drawing lines from 1 degree to 359 degree from center to the edge.

Does it suitable for this image ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think it all can be done with OpenCV. First based on this image, you could use simple masks to separate the colors. Then you could find the contours (cells) with findContours() for each color and finally use minEnclosingCircle() to fit circles on them, since you want diameter.

Comment: @Szala, I need to have exact diameter / area of the cell, not the area of circle which is on top of the cell.

Comment: You can find the area too with my proposed approach, `contourArea()` can calculate areas of the contours what are given as result of `findContours()`

Comment: @otto Please share what you have tried

Comment: @Jeru Luke, I just tried  to retrieve the contour of the areas that I want to measure. 
I found this idea https://answers.opencv.org/question/56095/draw-lines-from-centroid-of-contour-at-given-angle-till-edge-of-contour/ 

But not sure whether is it suitable to apply since I have a lot of pores needed to measure not only one. 

Measuring from the centroid seems not logical.